oasdiff --err-ignore flag doesn't ignore
Anyone has any idea on how to create this ignore file? the docs aren't clear and it basically says to just write the endpoint in it.
so after running oasdiff breaking my output is something like
error   [api-deprecated-sunset-parse] at packages/server/src/generated/swagger.json
        in API PUT /foo/bar
                api sunset date '' can't be parsed for deprecated API: 'sunset extension not found'

therefore I create a file with the endpoint named ignore.md (md is what the doc says people usually use) e.g.
PUT /foo/bar

however running
breaking --err-ignore ignore.md base revision

is still giving me the output with the error.

Found the solution, the full description from the error also had to be in the same line of the endpoint
PUT /foo/bar api sunset date '' can't be parsed for deprecated API: 'sunset extension not found'


nice job.  that's the way I mentioned in my answer.

You can try this
#cli command
oasdiff breaking <api1> <api2> --err-ignore ignore.md

The ignore file must be relative to where you run the command unless you add the proper path
# ignore.md
PUT /foo/bar this api is deprecated


I'm running oasdiff in the same directory of where the ignore.md file is stored, so that should just be ignore.md without any path right? I even tried with "./ignore.md" without success, also putting the flag after the  

what does your OpenAPI document look like? do you have a PUT with /foo/bar defined?  any other path parameters?
